# LINQ DeleteOnSubmit without Primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following code and I want to delete all rows from TABLE where the column 'id' IS NOT Primary Key.

```
@{
using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var query = db.Table.Where(r => r.id == 2).ToList();
    if (query != null)
    {
    foreach (var q in query)
    {
    db.Table.DeleteOnSubmit(q);
    }
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}}
```

This throws a System.InvalidOperationException because the table has not Primary Key column.

How is it possible to do that without adding a primary key in the SQL Server database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the LINQ Designer. Open the properties window for the table you want to delete a record from. Click on any of the columns in the entity you want to delete and you'll see a property labeled "Primary Key". Change the value to true for column you want to use as a primary key.

P/S:This will not set the primary key on your real table.